# foreach loop - case with different setting

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop giving out the results of a landscape gallery images.
Basically starting with

```
<?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>
```

and then the regular div + anchor + image tags for the gallery images.

```
<?php if ( $image->description == "portrait" ) :  ?>

<div id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box portrait" <?php echo $image->style ?> >


<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >

        <a class="portrait-image" href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title=" " id="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" rel="lightbox" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >           
        <img title="<?php  echo ' ' /* $image->alttext */ ?>" alt="<?php echo ' ' /* $image->alttext */ ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
        </a>

<?php else: ?>

<div id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box landscape" <?php echo $image->style ?> >


<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >

        <a class="landscape-image" href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title=" " id="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" rel="lightbox" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >          
        <img title="<?php  echo ' ' /* $image->alttext */ ?>" alt="<?php echo ' ' /* $image->alttext */ ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
        </a>


<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to have special case, where I have two portrait images side-by-side, filling the space of one landscape image.

What I was thinking about is to have a tag in the admin area which would trigger the break out of the foreach loop to have two images in one container div, and then it would continue the regular loop just with the container + image for the landscape images.
Is it possible in the case of foreach loop, to jump out of the loop, make a case with different settings, and then return to the regular looping method?

Comment: sounds more like a css thing here

Comment: Inside the loop, have an if/then for your special case. You can't "jump out of the loop" and back in.

Comment: What if the portrait images count were odd, what would you do in such case ?

Comment: @Lambasoft really good point!

Comment: @WasteD check my answer, I got it fixed

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't get it to work in my example, with the complicated array my Gallery program spits out. I updated the full code, maybe you could point me from there, please? 
If it doesn't work, I'll try the jQuery cut/paste method instead, not so nice, but it should also work.

Comment: @Gas why dont you check https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach($images as $key => $image) {
    if($image has special tag) { // <--- PSEUDOCODE 
        echo "<div class='SPECIAL_CSS_CLASS'><img src='" . $img->path . "' /></div>";
    }
}
```

Then in your CSS just do your Magic!

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead and do something like this:

```
//Function to get all the images based on a specific portrait_group
function getImagesPortraitGroup($group, $images) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if (isset($image['portrait_group']) && $image['portrait_group'] == $group) {
            $result[] = $image;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

//The images to show
$images = array(
    ["url" => "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "caption" => "Lorem Image1", "portrait_group" => 1],
    ["url" => "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "caption" => "Lorem Image2", "portrait_group" => 1],
    ["url" => "http://lorempixel.com/800/200/", "caption" => "Lorem Image3"],
    ["url" => "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "caption" => "Lorem Image4", "portrait_group" => 2],
    ["url" => "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/", "caption" => "Lorem Image5", "portrait_group" => 2],
);

//Everytime we show a group, we track it by adding it to this array in order not to show it again
$addedGroups = array();

//Loop through all the images
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
    echo "<div>";

    //If the image has a portrait_group that is not already shown, show it
    if (isset($images[$i]['portrait_group']) && !in_array($images[$i]['portrait_group'], $addedGroups)) {
        $groupImages = getImagesPortraitGroup($images[$i]['portrait_group'], $images);
        foreach ($groupImages as $image) {
            echo "<img src='{$image['url']}' title='{$image['caption']}' >";
        }
        //Save the group to the array in order not to show it again
        $addedGroups[] = $images[$i]['portrait_group'];
    } else {
        echo "<img src='{$images[$i]['url']}' title='{$images[$i]['caption']}' >";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get it to work, since I have already a predefined array in the Gallery management program, and I couldn't get around to make it work like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the grouping by jQuery, this is the code

```
jQuery(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box.portrait").filter(":odd").each(function(){
    $content = jQuery(this).find("a");
    jQuery(this).prev().find(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail").append($content);
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```